# How to compute the fundamental matrix from a pair of uncalibrated & non-parallel cameras?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, camera

As title, How to compute the fundamental matrix from a pair of **uncalibrated & non-parallel** cameras?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the dedicated matlab function [`estimateFundamentalMatrix`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/estimatefundamentalmatrix.html) for it. See the matlab manual for more information. This function will calibrate the camera setup based on at least 8 matched points in the two camera images.

Comment: estimateFundamentalMatrix is for stereo images according to the doc, does it apply to the non-parallel cameras?

Comment: Yes, I would think so. A lot of stereo application uses non-parallel cameras. The doc doesn't mention any assumptions about this. 8 points is enough to construct the fundamental matrix for any configuration.